# Some apps in WSL are inaccessible from the host OS while others are accessible on the same ports

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, port, ipv4

I've got Ubuntu in WSL 2 running on Windows 10 (Version 10.0.19044 Build 19044) host OS.

**Windows Defender Firewall is fully disabled**.

## What does work

1. A very basic [Express app](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) `index.js`:

   ```
   const express = require('express')
   const app = express()
   const port = 3000

   app.get('/', (req, res) => {
     res.send('Hello World!')
   })

   app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
   })
   ```

   Inside WSL, I run `npm init`, `npm i express` and finally `node index.js`.

   Then in a browser on the host OS I visit http://localhost:3000 and I see "Hello World!".
2. Other Node apps such as EmberJS:

   ```
   npx ember-cli -- new foo
   cd foo/
   npm start
   ```

   This starts a dev server on port 4200 inside WSL.

   Then in a browser on the host OS I visit http://localhost:4200 and I see a boilerplate app.

## What does not work

(of course, I make sure first that ports are available)

1. Running a Node `http-server`:

   I start `npx http-server -p 3000` inside WSL.

   [image]

   I access http://localhost:3000 in the host OS. Despite using the same port and host as before, I see "Connection refused".

   From inside WSL, the page does open (e. g. with `links http://localhost:3000`).
2. Running a Python HTTP server:

   I start `python3 -m http.server 4200` inside WSL.

   [image]

   I access http://localhost:4200 in the host OS. Despite using the same port and host as before, I see "Connection refused".

   From inside WSL, the page does open (e. g. with `links http://localhost:4200`).
3. Running headless Chrome with `--remote-debugging-port`.

   Chrome on the host OS is unable to connect to the headless Chrome in WSL.

## What I tried

Neither of these helps:

1. Rebooting.
2. `wsl --shutdown`.
3. Googling. A lot.

## Notes

When I start e. g. `npx http-server -p 4200`, an entry appears in the Network tab of the Resource Moninor in the host OS. It says port `4200`, process `wslhost.exe`, firewall status "Allowed, not restricted".

[image]

Yet, I see this:

[image]

**UPD 1**: I've been  over it for days, and I see individual attempts pass. Like once I've seen Chrome Inspector connect to the headless Chrome in WSL, twice I've seen `http-server` serve an index page. It hasn't worked for dozens of attempts, then it suddenly works once, then it stops working again.

At the same time, `node index.js` with Express and `ember serve` are 100% reliable and are always accessible from the host OS, even on the same port.

**UPD 2**: the problem does not happen with IPv6. Adding `-a ::` to `http-server` lets me connect reliably over IPv6. So why is IPv4 failing?!

Please help.

Comment: Good question (although network issues would probably be better on Super User), but please post the text (the first two screenshots) as code-blocks rather than images.  [This meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933) has some of the reasons why.  Thanks!

Comment: I wish I had some advice for you; I know you've been struggling for this for a bit.  Networking issues on WSL can be tricky.  It seems like you are attempting `localhost` (or the IPv4/v6 equivalent) for each connection, I believe?  What happens if you try the WSL2 IP address?  That is, the one found with `ip addr show eth0`?  Remember to bind the service to `0.0.0.0` if you do that, but I'm wondering if using the IP vs. `localhost` will have different results.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, I did try that and it does not make a difference.  Using IPv6 though does, even with localhost (::1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by Surfshark VPN, regardless of whether it was connected or not.

Uninstalling Surfshark from the host OS and rebooting resolved my issue.

Comment: So good to hear you got this resolved.

Comment: So while Surfshark installed you could solve that by providing routes for IPs and ports. Command `route`.